# Jquery on click not working while passing data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Question is very simple but due to some reason i am not able to fix it. 
Here is the **a href tag** that will open modal box.

```
<center><a href="javascript:void();" class="btn-home" data="<?php echo $cid;?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ApplyModal" name="btn-classified" id="btn-classified" href="#">Apply</a></center>
```

Here is jquery to get id from data attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('click', '#btn-classified', function() {
    //$("#btn-classified").on("click", function () {
     //$("#btn-classified").click(function() {   
     var myvar1 = $(this).data('data');
     alert(myvar1);

});
});
</script>
```

For some reason i am not getting any output if i use `$(document).on('click', '#btn-classified', function() {`
and if i use `$("#btn-classified").on("click", function () {` then i am getting undefined.

Comment: .data('data') will use the attribute data-data="", that's why you need to use Rui's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get 'data' attribute of `<a>` element use `.attr()` function of jQuery

```js
  $('document').ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#btn-classified', function() {
      var myvar1 = $(this).attr('data'); // .attr() to get attribute of an element
      alert(myvar1);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' id='btn-classified' data='This an element of DOM'>Get this DATA value</a>
```

Your Code get undefined on event `click` when your call to an element which exist after of the function.

You need performance the logic of your code, on jQuery you want use

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 //your functions with selectors of DOM 
})
```

or use `.on()` function of jQuery to events.

```
$(document).on('click', '.mainButton', function(){
 //your code
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.

Comment: Thanks to you. if this answer works for you choose as a correct

Answer (score 3):

You have two hrefs - one says `javscript:void();` the other has a hash (#) Remove one. Then you won't get undefined.

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is trying to access the data-attributes using a non-existing key.

Comment: @JethroVanThuyne it doesn't help to confuse the matter by pointing it to two locations. One href should still be removed

Comment: Nice catch i missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to change `data` to `data-id` in your HTML. That way you can access the data properties in your javascript like so:

```
$('#btn-classified').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

`$(this).data('data')` would actually expect `data-data="<?=$someId?>"` in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs  https://api.jquery.com/data/ the attribute should be  data-data
if it needs to be fetched through .data function.

```js
$('document').ready(function()
{
$(document).on('click', '#btn-classified', function() {
//$("#btn-classified").on("click", function () {
 //$("#btn-classified").click(function() {   
 var myvar1 = $(this).data('data');
 alert(myvar1);
});
});
```

```html
 <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<body>
<center>
  <a href="#" class="btn-home" data-data="123" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ApplyModal" name="btn-classified" id="btn-classified" >Apply
  </a>
  </center>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.

Answer (score 1):

Use .attr('data') instead of .data('data') functions because .data function is used to Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.